# Ошибка при выполнении команд в cmd из скрипта Python

Tags: python

Есть такой код:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig")
output = output.decode('cp866')
print(output)
```

При выполнении выдает в консоль ответ командной строки (все как нужно)...
Но если исправить "ipconfig" на что-нибудь другое, например "dir" или "echo hello", то при выполнении появляется ошибка (прикреплю скрин и Traceback), хотя просто в командной строке все команды выполняются без проблем...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Guest/PycharmProjects/sdfsdf/sfsdf.py", line 3, in <module>
  output1 = subprocess.check_output("dir")
File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in 
  check_output **kwargs).stdout
File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
  with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in 
  _execute_child startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

В чем загвоздка? Мне нужно, чтобы я мог из моего скрипта выполнять любые команды в командной строке.

[image: ipconfig]
[image: dir]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True)
```

И все работает!

Comment: Спасибо, это решило вопрос!

Comment: Я начал тестировать еще несколько команд и выяснил, что все же есть недочет... В то время как следующие команды работают исправно: start C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe tracert 192.38.21.114 То например команда: copy test.txt C:\Users\Guest\Desktop - выдает новую ошибку: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'copy test.txt C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: @Георгий Ну раз выдает ошибку, значит как раз именно копирование и не сработало. А в Питоне стандартная реакция на "не сработало" - исключение. Запустите команду копирования в командной строке, может там понятнее, в чем проблема. 

Если хотите вместо исключения просто получить код возврата команды и что-то решить в зависимости от его значения, используйте subprocess.call().

Answer (score 3):

В Windows (как в наследнике DOS) ни "echo", ни "dir" не являются внешними командами, но являются внутренними. Это значит, что они не представлены отдельными исполняемыми файлами, а специально "разбираются" интерпретатором (cmd.exe в данном случае). Попытка запустить такой файл как dir (а именно имя файла и аргументы хочет subprocess) ожидаемо приводит к описанной ошибке.